# Getting Last 4 Digits of Card using Customer Object - Stripe API

Tags: java, android, json, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe API and using below code I fetch details -

```
Customer cu = Customer.retrieve(customerid); // customerid
List<ExternalAccount> object = cu.getSources().getData();
Log.d("customerobj",object + "");
```

I get this object data

```
D/customerobj: [
  <com.stripe.model.Card@148232829id=>JSON: {
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": "71000",
    "address_zip_check": "pass",
    "available_payout_methods": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "currency": null,
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "default_for_currency": null,
    "description": null,
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 4,
    "exp_year": 2021,
    "fingerprint": "EmNhHLSbWLElhMvG",
    "funding": "credit",
    "iin": null,
    "issuer": null,
    "last4": "4242",
    "name": null,
    "recipient": null,
    "status": null,
    "three_d_secure": null,
    "tokenization_method": null,
    "type": null,
    "account": null,
    "customer": "cus_DL2GSWX9bfTZeU",
    "id": "card_1CuMC8A41bIzZYFFlpiW3hZp",
    "metadata": {

    },
    "object": "card"
  }
]
```

I want to get last 4 digits card number, exp_year, exp_month and address_zip.

Please help me get this String values

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: Get `0th` element of `object` which will return you object of `ExternalAccount` PoJo. After getting object of `ExternalAccount` PoJo just use their getters to fetch all values you require

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific key you can do:

```
object.get(index)
```

For exp_month, you would do `object.get(16)`, for exp_year, you would do `object.get(17)` and for last4 you would do `object.get(22)`

Comment: Hey James, `object` variable is a `List`.

Comment: Ah ok, so how would it be done? Is it object[0] or object.get(0), my mind just blanked out on me

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 1

Comment: a get this exception